# Two VideoView overlapping

Tags: android, view, android-videoview

I am making workout sample app. When one exercise is getting close to finish I would like to show small trailer of next exercise like below:

[image]

To accomplish that, I had to call:

```
videoViewTrailer.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
```

However when I hide trailer view I find myself left with frozen frame from trailer video which ruins my current exercise video. Here it is:
[image]

I already tried a lot of combination with using

```
VideoView.setZOrderMediaOverlay(true)
VideoView.setTranslationZ()
VideoView.setZOrderOnTop()
```

on both videoViews - and even calling:

```
View.invalidate()
```

but nothing seems to help.

How can I totally remove trailer video from my visible layout ?

PS. Mind I already offered nice views for help in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by **removing** and **readding** trailer **VideoView** from parent ViewGroup!
It turns out manipuating visibility or Z overlay param is not enought.

Comment: Visibility affects the View, not the Surface. Changes to Z-ordering must happen before the Surface is created.